# How to install SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 via NSIS

Tags: sql-server-ce, nsis

I'm looking for a sample NSIS script to detect and install only if necessary SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for my future self. Includes are:

```
!include "x64.nsh"
!include LogicLib.nsh
```

Section is as follows. The version check is testing for SP1

```
Section "SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 (required)"
    SectionIn RO

    ${If} ${RunningX64} 
        ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\ENU" "DesktopRuntimeVersion"
        DetailPrint "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (64 bit) DesktopRuntimeVersion=$0"
        ${If} $0 == '4.0.8876.1'
            DetailPrint "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SP1 (64 bit) is installed"
        ${Else}
            DetailPrint "Installing Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SP1 (64 bit)"
            SetDetailsPrint listonly
            ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\Tools\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe" /i /passive'
        ${EndIf}
    ${Else}
        ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\ENU" "DesktopRuntimeVersion"
        DetailPrint "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (32 bit) DesktopRuntimeVersion=$0"
        ${If} $0 == '4.0.8876.1'
            DetailPrint "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SP1 (32 bit) is installed"
        ${Else}
            DetailPrint "Installing Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SP1 (32 bit)"
            SetDetailsPrint listonly
            ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\Tools\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe" /i /passive'
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}

    SetDetailsPrint lastused

SectionEnd
```

As an aside, I've seen some blogs that say x86 AND x64 are required to be installed on a 64 bit system but if I run the x86 on a 64bit system then it errors out with not compatible. Hence only installing either or.

Comment: Nice one. Regarding your aside, on x64, SQL CE 3.5 requires x86 to be installed before x64. SQL CE 4.0 only x64 is needed